# Run macro based on cell contents if cell changes

Tags: excel, vba, cell, worksheet

I want to run a macro if a cell changes based only on the changed cell value. For instance, I want it to look at column F and if F4 and F5 already have data in it but I put in a value, which can be "MMD", "OPS", or "IMD", in cell F6 then I want it to run based on F6 contents only. Then, if I later leave F4, F5, and F6 as-is but change F7 in the same way it'll run based on the contents of F7 only. Namely, I want it to send a unique email to "IMD" if the changed cell contains "IMD", an email to "MMD" if the changed cell contains "MMD", and so on and to do so wherever the changed cell occurs in column F regardless of the rest of column F contents.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("F4")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range("F4:F20")) _
           Is Nothing Then

    If Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = "IMD" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook_IMD
    End If
    
    If Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = "MMD" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook_MMD
    End If
    
    If Sheet1.Range("F4").Value = "OPS" Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook_OPS
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `email?

Comment: There are other subs which are called in the body above ("Mail_small_Text_Outlook_IMD", for example) that send an email to a specific address if the cell contains the value "IMD"

Comment: But the sending mail part isn't what you are asking about.